# Query after parametric geometries in a GDB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

When you create an circle or ellipse in a GDB it is rendered as a parametric geometry storing x, y, radius, etc. and not as a polygon with nodes.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/parametric-circles-and-ellipses.htm

I have a layer with both polygons and parametric geometries (circles/ellipses). How do I make a query in ArcGIS 10.3 that returns only the parametric geometries and not the 'normal' node based polygons?

Comment: There is some ArcPy code at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37793/how-to-identify-true-arcs-in-arcmap that looks like it may provide you with a pathway to this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by opening the GDB in QGIS. This operation will remove all the records with parametric geometries. Using the objectid column I could identify the records with parametric geometries in the GDB that's not present in the QGIS striped version. Exporting the QGIS version to PostGIS and having ArcGIS exporting the GDB table to shape (this export converts the parametric geometries to polygons), importing the shape file to PostGIS and running the SQL did it

```
CREATE TABLE param_geom AS
SELECT a.*
FROM j_gdb a
LEFT JOIN gvkort.j b on a.objectid = b.objectid
WHERE b.objectid IS NULL
```

There may be ways in ArcGIS to do this another way, but my expertise lies elsewhere.