# Is there simple way to calculate radius of curvature along polyline?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polyline-creation, curvature

I am digitizing  a sinuous linear alignment (in this case a water pipe) and would like to get the radius of curvature of the various bends along the alignment. The main reason is that the  minimum curvature allowable for the exercise is of 200m (or approx 28 degrees along a 200m section).

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: A general solution is provided at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37058/algorithm-to-find-out-points-of-inflection-for-a-polyline.