Calculating degree of bend/curve/angle of road at specific points along a line feature class for roadkill study
I'm working on a set of roadkill data in a national park, with one of our aims being to figure out what makes certain sections of roads hotspot areas for roadkill.
I have a point feature layer of roadkill data (approx. 200 features), collected over 2 years, and a line feature layer of the one main road that runs through the national park.
One of our hypotheses is that there will be more roadkill on sharper bends/turns in the road. Ideally, I'm looking to associate the 'sharpness' of the turn/degree of the curve, for each roadkill incident.
Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to calculate this? I've done an extensive search online but have not been able to find anything.

Are you using ArcGIS Pro?
Here are some resources, although, nothing stuck out to me as an easy way to do it.
https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/determining-the-curvature-of-a-line-in-arc/td-p/711218
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195370/determining-curvature-of-polylines

You have done extensive research online? It took 5 seconds on google to find this highly relevant piece of work.

You could divide your line into some user-defined segments.  There are lots of ways to do this.  Maybe start with How To: Split a line into specified distances with a remainder.
Then calculate the sinuosity of those segments. Here is a tool for sinuosity but this is basically the line length of the segment divided by the distance between the ends.
Spatial join the points to the lines.  This will add a point (roadkill) count value to the lines.
